# Use array for array push instead of a string

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using the following code:

```
$patients_with_site = [];
if (in_array($zip_code, $current_zip_codes)) {
  echo "The referral id is: ".$referral_id;
  array_push($patients_with_site,$referral_id);
  print_r($patients_with_site);
}
```

I'm then trying to push it to a CSV file with this code:

```
$fp = fopen('patients_with_site.csv', 'w');

foreach ($patients_with_site as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

I'm getting an error saying that the `$patients_with_site` is a string and `fputcsv` requires an array.

Comment: _Small Point_ Its quicker to do a simple `$patients_with_site[] = $referral_id;` as that way there is no function call overhead

Comment: When you run `foreach ($patients_with_site as $fields)` the `$fields` var will be a string as `$patients_with_site` is an array of strings

Comment: What do you actually want the CSV file to look like??

Comment: Maybe what you intended to do was `fputcsv($fp, $patients_with_site);` without the loop

Comment: Also the first piece of code is NOT in an array, so what is the point of pushing the id into an array?? There will only ever be one, like Highlanders,

Answer (score 0):

If `fputcsv` requires array - provide array:

```
foreach ($patients_with_site as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, [$fields]);
}
```

And **yes**, every value of `$patients_with_site` is a string and not array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$patients_with_site`'s elements are strings.

The second argument of `fputcsv` must be an array, so unless you have a multidimensional array for `$patients_with_site` you shouldn't loop through it.

So it should work if you only call `fputcsv($fp, $patients_with_site)`.

See PHP [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#refsect1-function.fputcsv-parameters)

Comment: Using `fputcsv($fp, $patients_with_site)` will write all of the patients on one line separated by a comma.  You could specify a separator of PHP_EOL though.

Comment: I get it, didn't see it coming, but I am trying to explain why it's not working the way the function is being invoked